# Reports api in AppDynamics for generating custom report in csv or specific format

Tags: api, csv, appdynamics

I would like to know which existing api in AppDynamics can we use to generate custom reports. The use case is like, i am consolidating reports from multiple tools so,i would be using the API of app dynamics and doing a backend call to pull the data i need to display and putting it in a csv or excel.All of this will happen in an automated way, would like to know the api or any specific way to do the same in app dynamics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the REST API of the Controller described here https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO42/Using+the+Controller+APIs

To access the REST API Browser, in a Web browser, go to:

```
https://<controller_host>:<primary_port>/api-docs/index.html
```

this will give you a nice swagger UI description of the available resources.

Alternatively you can create reports directly out of the box in AppDynamics via the `Dashboards & Reports` section.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I used the app dynamics api using curl commands in python and automated the controller to track the data for a given period of time. Check it out: https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO42/AppDynamics+APIs